# What is the syntax error in the following SQL command?

Tags: sql, syntax

I want to set Restaurants.is_active to '0', where the user's email is the given value. Every syntax checker drops error, but I just can't get the solution.

```
UPDATE Restaurants  
 SET Restaurants.is_active = '0'  
 FROM Restaurants  
 INNER JOIN Users  
 ON Restaurants.id = Users.id  
 WHERE Users.email = 'something@gmail.com';
```

Comment: At least show us the error message!

Comment: In standard SQL there is no "FROM" clause for the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: please share the error message, without the message we can only guess

Comment: Column `is_active`'s data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Convert your `INNER JOIN` with an `EXISTS` clause, as follow, because `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` statement is not standard (only Sql Server use it):

```
UPDATE Restaurants  
SET Restaurants.is_active = '0'  
WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT 'user' FROM Users  
   WHERE Restaurants.id = Users.id  
   AND Users.email = 'something@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 UPDATE a
 SET is_active = '0'  
 FROM Restaurants a
 INNER JOIN Users  b
 ON a.id = b.id  
 WHERE b.email = 'something@gmail.com';
```